# i can't use explode php array

Tags: php

I get empty echo in 
and echo($file) not empty!!

```
      $files = glob($repertoireFichiersText."/*.php", GLOB_BRACE);
      var_dump($files);

        foreach($files as $k => $file) {
         echo "<br>File : " .  $file;

             $launch = array();
              $launch = explode("wp-admin/", $file);
              echo ($launch);
            }
```

I get empty echo
and echo($file) not empty!
who know where is it my problem and what is the solution

Comment: `var_dump($files);` show us the output of this

Comment: array(81) { [0]=> string(18) "wp-admin/about.php" [1]=> string(23) "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" [2]=> string(25) "wp-admin/admin-footer.php" [3]=> string(28) "wp-admin/admin-functions.php" [4]=> string(25) "wp-admin/admin-header.php" [5]=> string(23) "wp-admin/admin-post.php" [6]=> string(18) "wp-admin/admin.php" [7]=> string(25) "wp-admin/async-upload.php" [8]=> string(20) "wp-admin/comment.php" [9]=> string(20) "wp-admin/credits.php" [10]=> string(30) ....

Comment: Never post code in the comments, it's hard to read

Comment: Shouldn't this line 'echo ($launch);' be this 'echo ($launch[1]);'?

Comment: if you just want to strip "wp-admin/" off the string str_replace, instead of explode

Answer (score 0):

Only explode into 2 elements

```
$launch = explode("wp-admin/", $file, 2);
echo $launch[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to use explode, not the right tool for the job

```
$launch = str_replace("wp-admin/",'', $file);
echo $launch;
```

reference: [str_replace](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: please you can check my recent repose; i get just the first value of array